# Question about the definition of left/right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,\cdot)$ be a Magma. One defines another magma $(\mathcal{P}(A),\cdot)$ by letting

$\forall_{B,C\in\mathcal{P}(A)}B\cdot C :=\{b\cdot c :b\in B$ and $c\in C\}\subseteq A.$

The case where B or C is a singleton set is of particulair interest and one then unses the following simplified Notation:

$\forall_{B\in \mathcal{P}(A)}\forall_{a\in A}(a \cdot B := \{a\}\cdot B, B \cdot a := B \cdot\{a\}).$

Sets of the form $a\cdot B$ are called $left$ $cosets$, sets of the form $B \cdot a$ are called $right$ $cosets$

My Question is if you take for example the natural Numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with a Operation defined as $\cdot$ sucht that $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$ is a magma and you show that ${1}\cdot B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, for some subset of $\mathbb{N}$, is $1 \cdot \mathbb{N}$ then a left coset of $\mathbb{N}$ or do you have to show that ${a}\cdot B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ holds true for any $a\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking: if $\cdot$ is an operation on $\Bbb{N}$, then $a \cdot B \subseteq \Bbb{N}$ for any $a$ autormatically and $1 \cdot \Bbb{N}$ is a coset by definition. So what are you trying to prove?

Comment: For example let $\cdot$ be the usual multiplication and $B=\{2,3\}$, $1\cdot B$ would be equal to the set $\{2,3\}$ is this set then by definition a left coset? Or is the set $a\cdot B,a\in\mathbb{N} = \{2,3,4,6,8,9,12,....\}$ a left coset?